# Get the rowid of table on double click event in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using mvc4 and jquery.

I  am trying to find a way to make an entire row to fire doubleclick event.

My scenario is,  the model that contains the parameters Person ID, FirstName and Lastname.

But html table only show the FirstNmae and Lastname.

Where to store the person id ,if it hidden it will not get in javascript and space problem also.

My need is to, make the rows doubleclickable and that time  get the personID and second is to hide the person id from the enduser.

For getting personid I used,

```
$('#EditTable td').dblclick(function () {
    $(this).find('td:eq(1)')
    $(this).find('td:first').text()
}
```

but not get any value.

Comment: BTW, you do realise neither of your `find` calls do anything right? Also, don't forget to close your code with `);`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Solution**

The problem is that the event is firing for the `td` element, so `this` refers to the `td` element. You need to get the parent `tr` and then call the `find` function.

Something like this:

```
$('#EditTable td').dblclick(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var row = $this.closest("tr");
    row.find('td:eq(1)');
    row.find('td:first').text();
}); //<-- NOTE: you dont close correctly in your example, which cause console errors
```

[Here is a working example.](http://jsfiddle.net/nXyxS/)

---

**Alternatively**, you could assign the event to the `tr` element instead, which would allow you to keep your original function code...

```
$('#EditTable tr').dblclick(...
```

---

**Personally**, I would prefer to store "metadata" type things using a `data` attribute. For example:

```
$('#EditTable td').dblclick(function () {
    var $this = $(this);
    var row = $this.closest("tr");
    var id = row.data("id");
});
```

with the following html table:

```
<table id="EditTable">
    <tr data-id="1">
        <td>1</td><td>One</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Here is a working example using data attributes.](http://jsfiddle.net/nXyxS/1/)

Answer (score 1):

Actually you can store the model details in DOM tree using `$.data('personID',1)` method. In that way you can hide the `personID` from the user. When the user dbl clicks on a row, get the corresponding `personID` like `$.data('personID')`

```
//setting the personID
$.data('personID',2);

//getting the personID
$.data('personID'); //returns 2
```

Comment: how this value setting in razor view table ?

Comment: @Html.Hidden("PhoneId", @item.PhoneId)

Answer (score 0):

You have to write:

```
// You want event fired on row `tr` and not on `td`
$('#EditTable tr').dblclick(function () {
    $(this).find('td:eq(1)')
    $(this).find('td:first').text()
}
```

**Edit**

Best way would be:

```
$('#EditTable').on(dblclick, 'tr', function () {
    var $rowClicked = $(this);
    var secondCell = $rowClicked.find('td:eq(1)');
    var textOfFirstCell $rowClicked.find('td:first').text();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('#EditTable tr').dblclick(function () {
  var $this=$(this);
  $this.find('td:first').text(); //get personid
  $this.find('td:first').hide(); //hide the personrow... u can use remove()
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this one:

```
 $('#EditTable tr').dblclick(function () {
   $(this).find('td:eq(1)')
   $(this).find('td:first').text()
 });
```

Try to iterate through `TRs` instead and may be that's a typo or what you have a error at closing that should be `});`